# Creating an IntelliJ plugin to handle file type with no extension

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to create an IntelliJ plugin to handle custom language support by following this tutorial: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Custom+Language+Support.  My problem is the files I want to provide support for are called "Config", with no extension.  The LanguageFileType class seems to only support matching files based on extension, though.  Is there any way to register a regex for the filename instead of just the extension?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to do this - In the FileTypeFactory, pass a FileNameMatcher as the 2nd argument to the `consume` call:

```
public class ConfigFileTypeFactory extends FileTypeFactory {
    @Override
    public void createFileTypes(FileTypeConsumer consumer) {
        consumer.consume(BrazilConfigFileType.INSTANCE, new ExactFileNameMatcher("Config"));
    }
}
```